# What does ことになってんだ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, particle-に, sentence, sentence-final-particles

> しばらく構ってやれないが良い子にできるか?

Which is "I won't be able to keep company to you for a while, but will you still be a good kid/behave?"

To which the character screams this reply:

[image]

I'm stumbled on the exact nuance of ことになってんだ in this. From context he seems... to be saying "How did it became that he's looking after me"? "Why did it become like he's looking after me?"

I assume the first bubble it's just a なんで but the actual nuance of ことになってんだ is what I'm not sure about.

I suppose it may ことになってる but it has various meanings so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your understanding of the ことになってる part is not bad. The main problem is the interpretation of 俺が構われている. Nothing in your sentence says 彼, so maybe you've confused 俺 (I) and 彼 (he)? Or maybe you've missed the passive voice in this part? 俺が構われてる is short for 俺が構われている, which is passive-progressive.

> 俺は(お前に)構われて(い)る。
>
> I am being looked after (by you).

> なんで俺が構われてるみたいなことになってんだ！
>
> - Why did it turn out that I am being looked after!?
> - Why am I supposed to be looked after (by you)?
> - Why am I being treated as if I need care?